# Why encapsulation is good for interchangeability and working in team?

Tags: encapsulation

That's my question.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encapsulation is good because you can protect the values of variables and what variables can be seen/edited.

Here's an example in Java:

```
public class Foo {
    private int size;
    private String name;

    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public void setSize(int size) {
        if (size > 0)
            this.size = size;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        if (name == null || name.isEmpty())
            return;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

This makes sure that the variable size is greater than 0 and the value of name isn't empty or `null`. You can also put checks in the constructor.

One more thing. If you had made the variable size `public`, and everyone used `fooObject.size=232`, and then suddenly you wanted to make restrictions, it would break everybody's code. It's better just to start by using encapsulation.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: So I think it is clear.  It is good for interchangeability because with the encapsulation of the setSize() you can be sure of saving a good data   and good for working in team, because the same as for the interchangeability.